# Limit the number of categories appearing in the woocommerce single product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to limit the number of categories appearing in the woocommerce single product page. Currently the `meta.php` in the "single-product" folder is grabbing all the categories for display. I want to limit it to 4 or 5.

I couldn't understand `$product->get_categories()` in the file. would appreciate if this would be sorted

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what you are actually doing (eg. provide a minimal snippet of code) and what is missing/not working?

Answer (score 0):

You can echo the following short code to display a list of categories within a template file, 6 being the number of categories on display:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[product_categories number='6' parent='0']"); ?>
```

You can either make your own template for use or over ride whatever bloated code woocommerce has used.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this, by using some default php functions.
The logic is to create an array from the string generated by $product->get_categories( ', ' ) default woocommerce function using the [implode()](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.implode.php) php function.
After this, you limit the number of result by getting a slice of the array using the [array_slice()](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.array-slice.php) php function. setting the second parameter will be the number of results (in my example this is 5).
When done limiting, we should convert our array back to a comma separated string using the [explode()](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.explode.php) php function.

SHORT VERSION:

```
echo implode(', ', (array_slice((explode(', ', $product->get_categories( ', ' ))), 0, 5, true)));
```

LONGER, EXPLAINED VERSION:

```
$categories_string = $product->get_categories( ', ' );
$categories_array = explode(', ', $categories_string);
$categories_to_display_array = array_slice($categories_array, 0, 5, true);
$categories_to_display_string = implode(', ', $categories_to_display_array);
echo $categories_to_display;
```